# Shapeless lenses in idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, shapeless

I try to use shapless lenses of version 2.0.0 for scala 2.10.3
I have the code similar to this one:

```
import shapeless._
case class A(map: Map[String, String])
case class B(a: A)
val mapLens = lens[B] >> 'a >> 'map
```

the infered type in idea of `mapLens` is

```
AnyRef with Lens[B, Nothing] {val gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[Nothing, ::[record.FieldType[Witness.Lt[Symbol]#T, Nothing], Nothing]]}
```

so if I want to change value of B instance

```
mapLens.set(b)(b.a.map + ("foo" -> "bar"))
```

I get a type mismatch error. How to fix this?

P.S. [Here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/lenses.scala) there is an example of using shapeless lenses. How does this `lens[Person].address.street` works? I mean how does compiler allow us to call methods of case class on instance of lense class? Because in `LenseExamples` object the >> operator is used

**edit**
Have tried in REPL and it works. Idea says that it

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type shapeless.LabelledGeneric[B]{type Repr = Out0}
```

The same complain emits gradle

Comment: Have you tried this outside IDEA (ie. using SBT, or in Eclipse)?

Comment: No, haven't tried yet? Can this be a reason? My IDEA uses compiler of vresion 2.10.3 as well as gradle project where this code resides

Comment: All I can say is that I tried your example briefly on the REPL and I didn't see `Nothing` inferred anywhere.

Comment: Suppose it works in scala REPL and sbt because they have dependecy on scala compiler(either compile or runtime dependecy). When adding runtime dependency of scala compiler to gradle and running `gradle scalaConsole` task it works. However, when I build or test my project through gradle it emits the same error with implicit evidence absence

Answer (score 8):

Idea is wrong. You should report a bug against the Scala plugin.

Comment: scalac is definitive.

Comment: I have created an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8710 When searching for shapeless in the issue tracker quite some issues come up. Bummer.