# How do scala developers cope with incorrect IDE(Idea) errors in scala code with shapeless

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, ide, shapeless

This is a general question with a specific example.

How do people getting into scala and using it for big projects handle unreliability of tools/IDE? Do you just accept red markings all over your source code?

I encounter yet another scala codebase where working code is flagged red by idea `Cannot resolve symbol Repr`.

I start a playground project to explore one of libraries in the codebase - shapeless (as I understand it a highly regarded library in scala community).

I write extremely basic code from the first page of official shapeless guide.

```
package example
import shapeless._

object Hello extends App {
  val genericEmployee = Generic[Employee].to(Employee("Dave", isOld = true))
  val genericIceCream = Generic[IceCream].to(IceCream("yellow", isInCone = false))

  def genericCsv (gen: String :: Boolean :: HNil) :List[String] = List(gen(0), gen(1).toString())

  println(genericCsv(genericIceCream).toString())
}

case class Employee (name: String, isOld: Boolean)

case class IceCream (name: String, isInCone: Boolean)
```

`gen(0)` and `gen(1)` are flagged with `No implicits found for parameter at hlist.At[String :: Boolean :: HNil, Nat#N]`

The code works.

I also remember errors-but-not-real-errors being caused by Akka HTTP.

Comment: Use **metals** instead: https://scalameta.org/metals/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be a fundamental difficulty in IntelliJ supporting libraries relying on macros such as shapeless

[@niktrop](https://gitter.im/JetBrains/intellij-scala?at=5a548d1a0505ad8b45d11c85)

> Shapeless is heavily using macros. We have no way to support them
>   generically.

[@joroKr21](https://gitter.im/JetBrains/intellij-scala?at=5a54fa8bb48e8c3566bcf0e9)

> there is a fundamental barrier for whitebox macros. You have to run a
>   complete typecheck and expand them just to see what type they return
>   and this is not feasible to do on every keystroke. Blackbox macros on
>   the other hand shouldn't pose such problems.

[@olafurpg](https://gitter.im/JetBrains/intellij-scala?at=5a55112fce68c3bc749a5345)

> scala-compiler and intellij-scala are different typecheckers,
>   scala-reflect macros are currently implemented against scala-compiler
>   APIs which makes them difficult to support in alternative scala
>   compilers.

---

You could try reporting highlighting errors as a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23899094/5205022) at

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL

Here is an example you could use as a template

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-16091

Select the affected subsystem as `Error Highlighting`

This feature is called [Type-aware highlighting](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2011/03/02/type-aware-highlighting/) and can be disabled by clicking on the little `T` icon in bottom right corner

[image]

> How to deal with false errors?
>
> So, the truth is you have to remember that sometimes there’s no spoon
>   error. To help us to fix a highlighting glitch you may report it to
>   YouTrack as usual or by pressing Alt+Enter on wrong highlight: